# I dont know how to properly search in SIMBAD

Tags: star, resource-request

I've been trying to search in SIMBAD for a star in about 92 parsecs,
there is a problem. I dont know how to properly search,

I got confused with the query search with those bazillion codes, and every time i try to search by how i think it would go it only says
**Lexical error at line 1, column 19. Encountered: "9" (57) Distance.distance 92 pc**

and the guides do not help at all, I want ot search a concrete list of stars that area in a 91-92 parsec distance from sol, Other resources for me were very limited

I need help
https://simbad.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-fsam

Comment: You definitely want to be more specific. What do you look for? What did you try? What result do you get? What did you expect? And why is the provided help not sufficient? Until you make the question answerable: -1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The help in the search form is pretty clear and addresses your problem in the example:
[image: simbad query view]

You look for parallax, `plx`:
Plx <92 & plx >91

Change the radio box below the example to return an actual list of objects (display). By default it only returns only the object count (as you see in the screenshot, that is active there, too)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man :)